# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;location&#39; of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, angular5

Been trying to post a product with an image using AWS S3 (Multer and MulterS3). Each time I use the postman I receive "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" which is the line where I have the Image variable. What I'm I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const Product = require('../models/product');

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ accessKeyId: "--", secretAccessKey: "--"});

const checkJWT = require('../middlewares/check-jwt');





var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: '365techhubwebapplication',
        metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldName});
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString())
          }
          
    })
});


router.route('/products')
.get((req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
        success: "Hello"
    });
})

.post([checkJWT, upload.single('product_picture')], (req, res, next) => {
     console.log(upload);
     console.log(req.file);
    let product = new Product();
    product.owner = req.decoded.user._id;
    product.category = req.body.categoryId;
    product.title = req.body.title;
    product.price = req.body.price;
    product.description = req.body.description;
    product.image = req.file.location;
    
    product.save();
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully Added the product'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your req.file is undefined. So, you can't read req.file.location

Comment: Then How can I define it? Please help me im new to this framework. Im using Node.js and Angular5.

Comment: You have posted your amazon s3 access key and secret key in this question. I am quit surprised. Do not post confidential information in code, if it is real access key and secret key.

Comment: Thanks for the observation @SudhirOjha. I did that unknowingly. Have edited it. Thanks brov

Answer (score 0):

Your req.file is undefined, please send req.file or add check and update your code like this:

```
.post([checkJWT, upload.single('product_picture')], (req, res, next) => {
     console.log(upload);
     console.log(req.file);
    let product = new Product();
    product.owner = req.decoded.user._id;
    product.category = req.body.categoryId;
    product.title = req.body.title;
    product.price = req.body.price;
    product.description = req.body.description;
    if (req.file) { // Checking if req.file is not empty.
        product.image = req.file.location;
    }
    product.save();
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully Added the product'
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow Thank you so much Jack! Got a successful added the product message but my bucket is empty.  Which folder is req.file located so that I can check and once it 's found what should I do?

Comment: Its the request header parameter you are sending. Ensure if you are sending req.file in header.

Comment: Yes @Jack I have this console.log(upload);
     console.log(req.file);

Comment: Successfully Added the product received but my bucket is empty

Comment: @365Techsolutions, I think I have given you answer for the question, "TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;location&#39; of undefined". So you can close this question by accepting answer and ask new question with more details regarding the other problem you are having.

Comment: Noted @Jack. Thanks